# How to use an "is" method

Tags: java, methods

I have to create an object that uses an "is" method, basically declaring the state of the object. I am not sure how this should work. Right now am writing the method as a boolean but I am wondering if I should use a different approach, here is the code,

```
public class Cell
{
    public int move;

    public Cell(int xmove)
    {
        xmove = 0;
    }
    public boolean isempty(int x)
    {
        if(x == 0)
        {   
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is nowhere near enough info. How do you expect us to know what the method should do?

Comment: Boolean is a good choice for methods like `isSomething` or `hasSomething` :)

Comment: What is an "is" method? a method which contains "is" in it's name?

Comment: As far as I understand the question, you need to implement a method which name should start with `is`. I don't know if it helps, but `is...` methods by convention return a boolean.

Comment: It looks like your isempty() function isn't testing an instance of your class. I would think isempty() would take no arguments and return true or false based on the instance or make it static and take an instance as argument so you can do this: Cell.isempty(new Cell())

Answer (score 13):

You are kind of on the right track but there are a bunch of issues.

First, this is much simpler

```
 public boolean isEmpty(){
    return move == 0;
 }
```

I assumed that an instance of Cell is empty if its move is 0.

Note that I've camel cased your method name.  Also, `isEmpty` is supposed to say something about the state of an object.  It doesn't make sense to pass in `x` (unless you want to compare x to some property on the object instance).

Second, you constructor takes an argument, then sets it to 0.  That's not going to do anything.  You probably want

```
public Cell(int move){
    this.move = move;
}
```

Which takes an argument and sets the field on the current instance that is being constructed to the value passed in (you defined a field `move`, so you probably want to set it.).

So you could do something like

```
Cell cell1 = new Cell(1);
Cell cell2 = new Cell(0);

cell1.isEmpty() // false;
cell2.isEmpty() // true;
```

Comment: +1 , maybe also address the fact he sets the parameter passed to the constructor to 0. That makes little sence